# Как вывести кол-во сообщений в кнопку телеграмм

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть кнопка "Список" - выводит ВЕСЬ список по категориям. Как мне сделать так чтоб кнопка выглядела "Список - N", где N - кол-во этих самых сообщений.

```py
if message.text == 'Список':  # список сохранённых данных
            conn = sqlite3.connect("list.db")
            c = conn.cursor()
            lists = "SELECT id, user_id, text FROM 'user_message' where user_id={}".format(
                message.chat.id)
            c.execute(lists)
            text = 'ID|    Ваш ID    | Сообщение\n\n'
            text = text + "\n".join(['| '.join(map(str, x)) for x in c])
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, reply_markup=delete_button)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

если под "N = кол-во сообщений" Вы имеете в виду кол-во категорий из Списка, то:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    spisok = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
    start_k = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Список - " + str(len(spisok)), 
    callback_data='catalog')
    start_k.add(item)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать", reply_markup=start_k)
```

таким образом кнопка будет выглядеть "Список - 5", где 5 это кол-во элементов в списке spisok.

Если же я понял Ваш вопрос неправильно, напишите в комментариях более подробно

Comment: я имел в виду категории в БД,не списка

Comment: Оператор SQL COUNT() — функция возвращающая количество записей (строк) таблицы. Запись функции с указанием столбца вернет количество записей конкретного столбца за исключением NULL записей.